# Little Endian in gdb

Tags: x86, gdb, endianness

```
        0x0      0x6      0x0       0x1
```

BIG - 00000000  00000110  00000000 00000001

LIT - 00000001  00000000  00000110 00000000

So I was expecting 0xcfb01420 + 2 to be 0x6, but that is not the case. Am I missing something?

```
(gdb) p &tx_q_sem->mlock.u.mtxa_owner
$41 = (volatile __uintptr_t *) 0xcfb01420
(gdb) p/x tx_q_sem->mlock.u.mtxa_owner
$34 = 0x601
(gdb) p (char)*(char*)(0xcfb01420+0)
$36 = 0x1
(gdb) p (char)*(char*)(0xcfb01420+1)
$37 = 0x6
(gdb) p (char)*(char*)(0xcfb01420+2)
$38 = 0x0
(gdb) p (char)*(char*)(0xcfb01420+3)
$39 = 0x0
```

My assumption is that byte sequence for 0x601 in little endian format should match the way I represented it above. Therefore second byte should have been all zeros. There I have put all the nibbles correctly I guess.

Comment: Use `x /4xb 0xcfb01420` to eXamine the 4 bytes in memory, showing each byte separately.  Much easier than printing them.  Although you could also have done `p /x (char[4]) tx_q_sem->mlock.u.mtxa_owner`, I think.

Comment: Thanks for comment, however I think I did not convey my question as clearly I wanted. Nothing changes even with your method. My problem is the little endian is not shown correctly in GDB. 0x6 should have been at third byte for x86 little endian format. (gdb) x /4xb 0xcfb01420 gives me 
0xcfb01420:     0x01    0x06    0x00    0x00. Or is it that my conversion itself is wrong?

Comment: Remember that one byte is 2 hex digits (nibbles) wide.  Tom's answer is correct, you're getting confused by gdb omitting the leading zeros when printing each byte separately.  The place value of the `6` in `0x601` is 2^8: it's `6 * (1U << 8)` which is the bottom of the *2nd* byte.

Comment: Thanks, request you to please verify the representation in big/little endian format for 0x601 as I presented at the top.

Comment: Those are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the premise itself was wrong. Both of you were right, I got confused  and treated leading zeros in a different nibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial hex values are all missing digits, relative to what you're actually examining.

`00000001` is `0x01` -- it is 8 binary digits, so a full byte.

So `0x601` == `0x0601` ==  `00000110 00000001`.

You can see this in gdb with:

```
(gdb) print /t 0x601
$1 = 11000000001
```